# Fail to use datetime with deadpool-postgres

Tags: postgresql, rust

I want to select a timestamp from my postgres db.

This is how my a part of my cargo.toml

```
deadpool-postgres = {version = "0.10.1"}
chrono = "0.4.19"
tokio-postgres = { version = "0.7.2", features = ["with-chrono-0_4"] }
```

This is the code that does the select:

```
let mut client: Client = db_pool.get().await?;
let transaction = client.transaction().await?;
let row = transaction.query_one("SELECT name, description, created FROM host WHERE host_id = $1", &[&host_id]).await?;
let host_name = row.get(0);
let host_description = row.get(1);
let a: chrono::DateTime<chrono::offset::Utc> = row.get(2);
```

This is the error I get:

```
thread 'actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:0' panicked at 'error retrieving column 2: error deserializing column 2: cannot convert between the Rust type `chrono::datetime::DateTime<chrono::offset::utc::Utc>` and the Postgres type `timestamp`', /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-postgres-0.7.5/src/row.rs:151:25
```

I think I have configured everything, according to the docs at https://docs.rs/deadpool-postgres/0.10.1/deadpool_postgres/index.html.

Comment: I believe you didn't put a TIMESTAMPTZ in your posgresql type, but TIMESTAMP and so I guess you should use https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/naive/struct.NaiveDateTime.html

Comment: You are right, thanks. If you post an answer could you also post the source of our knowledge.